# Is there a rule for which overloaded routine gets chosen if there are multiple candidates?

Tags: delphi, generics, overloading

I'm trying to trick the compiler into choosing a specific overloaded method out of multiple available options.

If the compiler chooses a method with a generic parameter, it will always get passed by reference, but for inlining reasons I prefer the parameters to be passed by value.

However I'm struggling to find a clear rule determining how the compiler selects which overloaded method to call.

Consider the following code:

```
program Project45;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  TX = type byte;

  TTest<T> = class
    class function Compare(const a,b: T): shortstring; overload; static; inline;
    class function Compare(const a,b: integer): shortstring; overload; static; inline;
    class function Compare(const a,b: cardinal): shortstring; overload; static; inline;
    class function Compare(const a,b: shortint): shortstring; overload; static; inline;
    class function Compare(const a,b: byte): shortstring; overload; static; inline;
    class function Compare(const a,b: smallint): shortstring; overload; static; inline;
    //class function Compare(const a,b: T): shortstring; overload; static; inline;
  private
  end;

class function TTest<T>.Compare(const a, b: integer): shortstring;
begin
  Result:= 'Integer compare';
end;

class function TTest<T>.Compare(const a, b: byte): shortstring;
begin
  Result:= 'Byte compare';
end;

class function TTest<T>.Compare(const a, b: smallint): shortstring;
begin
  Result:= 'Smallint compare';
end;


class function TTest<T>.Compare(const a, b: int8): shortstring;
begin
  Result:= 'Shortint Compare';
end;

class function TTest<T>.Compare(const a, b: cardinal): shortstring;
begin
  Result:= 'Cardinal compare';
end;

class function TTest<T>.Compare(const A,B: T): shortstring;
begin
  Result:= 'Generic compare';
end;

function test: boolean;
var
  A,B: byte;
  c,d: shortint;
  w1,w2: word;
  e,f: TX;
begin
  a:= 1; b:= 255;
  c:= 1; d:= -1;
  e:= 1; f:= 255;
  WriteLn('TTest<byte>.Compare(byte)'+#9+(TTest<byte>.Compare(a, b)));
  WriteLn('TTest<shortint>.Compare(byte)'+#9+(TTest<shortint>.Compare(a, b)));
  WriteLn('TTest<byte>.Compare(shortint)'+#9+(TTest<byte>.Compare(c, d)));
  WriteLn('TTest<shortint>.Compare(shortint)'+#9+(TTest<shortint>.Compare(c, d)));
  WriteLn('TTest<smallint>.Compare(word)'+#9+(TTest<smallint>.Compare(w1, w2)));
  WriteLn('TTest<smallint>.Compare(smallint)'+#9+(TTest<smallint>.Compare(smallint(w1), smallint(w2))));
  WriteLn('TTest<shortint>.Compare(tx)'+#9+#9+(TTest<shortint>.Compare(e, f)));
  WriteLn('TTest<TX>.Compare(tx)'+#9+#9+(TTest<TX>.Compare(e, f)));
  ReadLn;
end;

begin
  Test;
end.
```

If I put the generic method first in the class the following is output:

```
TTest<byte>.Compare(byte)   ->            Generic compare  
TTest<shortint>.Compare(byte) ->          Byte compare  
TTest<byte>.Compare(shortint) ->          Shortint Compare  
TTest<shortint>.Compare(shortint)  ->     Generic compare   
TTest<smallint>.Compare(word) ->          Integer compare  
TTest<smallint>.Compare(smallint)  ->     Generic compare  
TTest<shortint>.Compare(tx)       ->      Byte compare  
TTest<TX>.Compare(tx)      ->             Generic compare
```

If I put the generic method last, the output changes to:

```
TTest<byte>.Compare(byte)    ->           Byte compare  
TTest<shortint>.Compare(byte) ->          Byte compare  
TTest<byte>.Compare(shortint) ->          Shortint Compare  
TTest<shortint>.Compare(shortint) ->      Shortint Compare  
TTest<smallint>.Compare(word) ->          Integer compare  
TTest<smallint>.Compare(smallint)  ->     Smallint compare  
TTest<shortint>.Compare(tx)     ->        Byte compare  
TTest<TX>.Compare(tx)      ->             Generic compare
```

The first one has a really random feel to it, the second one makes more sense, but sometimes changing the type parameter makes to compiler change its call, sometimes changing the parameters themselves effects a change.

**What rule does the compiler use to select which overloaded method to call?**

Comment: In grown up languages like C++, C#, Java etc., overload resolution is defined clearly and unambiguously. It's high time that Delphi grew up.

Comment: Time to file a bug-report?

Comment: I think that is the right thing to do. I guess I'm just too jaded. Do you think that this Q is a dupe?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, yes it's a dupe. Feel free to close it as such.

Comment: Filed: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-11353

Comment: I think it's probably fair to say that the overload resolution rules are clearly and unambiguously *defined*, otherwise the compiler would produce random results on each pass over the same code.  What's missing (or inaccurate/incomplete) is the *documentation* of those rules.   I anticipate that one reason for the lack of full disclosure w.r.t the rules is that they are a complete and utter mess.  So publishing the rules as-is is unlikely, but cleaning them up so they **can** be published will almost certainly result in potentially breaking changes.  Neither is really satisfactory.

Comment: @Deltics, a compiler switch would easily solve that.

Comment: @Deltics the close action removed my first comment which identified the dupe and said also that there is no reliable documentation for the rules. It's clear that rules exist but Emba have not yet published the rules.

Comment: @Johan Even if the rules were well documented, this is a dangerous game. You can add a new overload and cause havoc downstream. I know you are attracted to this kind of coding and it does have an attraction. But in my experience, anytime you rely on rules to find a "best" match then trouble lies ahead. My advice is to use overloading when resolution must find a unique match. As soon as you have multiple candidates then danger lies ahead.

Comment: @Johan - a compiler switch can solve a lot of things.  How many switches would you like ?  How many different variations in compiler behaviour are you comfortable with Embarcadero reliably maintaining ? (or attempting to).  Unfortunately we don't live in an Ideal World and I have sadly little confidence in Embarcadero's ability to do the required job well enough to avoid simply making things worse. :(

Comment: The duplicate question doesn't seem to answer this question. It's not hard to come up with simple resolution rules that fit the observed behavior here: If there is no exact match, then promote integral types and use the corresponding match. Otherwise, use the first matching function. The first code example doesn't look random to me at all; it's the same as the second one, except for the selection of the generic methods, which are each replaced with the non-generic methods in the second code because the non-generic method duplicates the generic method, but is declared first.

Comment: @Rob I'm still waiting for an answer. It's not too late to add one.